# Strtol function giving strange logic errors

Tags: c

I'm creating a program that inputs six strings and converts them to integers, adds them, and outputs the result.

However, the program sometimes outputs the correct result, but strangely, it can also output 30 when the total should have been 28 or 29.

```
// Inputs six strings and converts them to integers for calculations
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define AMOUNT 6
#define SIZE 12

int main(void)
{
    // string array where inputs are stored
    char *inputs[7] = {"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"};
    
    // get six strings representing integers
    for (unsigned short int counter = 0; counter < AMOUNT; counter++) {
        printf("%s", "Enter an integer: ");
        
        fgets(&inputs[counter], SIZE, stdin);
        
        puts("");
    }
    
    // long array where converted numbers are stored
    long convertedInteger[6];
    
    // pointer to convert integers
    char *Ptr;
    
    for (unsigned short int counter = 0; counter < AMOUNT; counter++) {
        convertedInteger[counter] = strtol(inputs, &Ptr, 0);
    }
    
    // output variable
    long long int output = 0;
    
    // loop to add integers to total
    for (unsigned short int counter = 0; counter < AMOUNT; counter++) {
        output += convertedInteger[counter];
    }
    
    // print output variable
    printf("The total is %lld", output);
}
```

Edit:
Here's the warnings I'm receiving. Some of them don't seem to be
coming from my program. I'm using Dev-C++ 5.11 and compiling to C11.

[image: list of program warnings]

Comment: `fgets(&inputs[counter], SIZE, stdin);` should have given problems, no?, might think about using `malloc`

Comment: No, it doesn't give errors for some reason... It does give a warning though.

Comment: Warnings are important.

Comment: I found the problem. The program is reading only the first input, then adding it to the total six times, but I'm not good with pointers and I'm not sure how to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try that. However, don't I need the first index of the multidimensional array to be AMOUNT + 1 to account for the terminating character?

Comment: Often enough warnings point out unclean code that might get into real issues under unfortunate circumstances. Make it a habit to 1. always have `-Wall` enabled, and 2. immediately fix them.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Obsoleted by Q edit.

> long long int output;

Basic beginner's error: [Uninitialized variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable).

Comment: I tried initializing the variable, but it didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by making the input variable a multidimensional char array. I'll put the modified code below.

```
// Inputs six strings and converts them to integers for calculations
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define AMOUNT 6
#define SIZE 12

int main(void)
{
    // string array where inputs are stored
    char inputs[AMOUNT][SIZE];
    
    // get six strings representing integers
    for (unsigned short int counter = 0; counter < AMOUNT; counter++) {
        printf("%s", "Enter an integer: ");
        
        fgets(inputs[counter], SIZE, stdin);
        
        puts("");
    }
    
    // long array where converted numbers are stored
    long convertedInteger[6];
    
    for (unsigned short int counter = 0; counter < AMOUNT; counter++) {
        char *convertedPtr;
            
        convertedInteger[counter] = strtol(inputs[counter], &convertedPtr, 0);
    }
    
    // output variable
    long long int output = 0;
    
    // loop to add integers to total
    for (unsigned short int counter = 0; counter < AMOUNT; counter++) {
        output += convertedInteger[counter];
    }
    
    // print output variable
    printf("The total is %lld", output);
}
```